# Sort array of dictionaries in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have an array which contains multiple dictionaries.
see example below:

**Example:**

`Main Array:`

```
(
    {
        Title: "A";
        Value: 1;
        Priority: 
        (
            4  //Problem: contains array as value which need to be sorted
        );
    },
    {
        Title: "B";
        Value: 2;
        Priority: 
        (
            3 //Problem: contains array as value which need to be sorted
        );
    },
    {
        Title: "C";
        Value: 3;
    },
    {
        Title: "D";
        Value: 4;
        Priority: 
        (
        );
    },
    {
        Title: "E";
        Value: 5;
        Priority: null
    },
)
```

I need to sort the main array as per "Priority" in dictioanry.
Priority values are as an array.

How can I achieve this sorting?

Help me to solve this...

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Are your priorities strings or numbers?

Comment: @Rob, Actually I have to convert into Integer from String & then Sort out them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSSortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Title" ascending:YES];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
```

Or other option could be  `sortedArrayUsingComparator`

```
[arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *item1, NSDictionary *item2) {
    NSString *first = [item1 objectForKey:@"Title"];
    NSString *second = [item2 objectForKey:@"Title"];
    return [first compare:second options:NSLiteralSearch];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply... but I want to sort according to "Priority".

Comment: what u storing in prority

Comment: So what is your sorting rule? Based on the lowest value in each priority array? The highest? The average?

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks for your reply...  the highest will at first.

Comment: if priority key will contain single value why you have used array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you need the reverse then just change the order of if-else condition

```
[mainArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *dic1, NSDictionary *dic2) {
    int priority1 = [[[dic1 objectForKey:@"Priority"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int priority2 = [[[dic2 objectForKey:@"Priority"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

    if(priority1 < priority2) return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if(priority1 > priority2) return NSOrderedDescending;
    else return NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSArray *mainArray = @[
                       @{
                           @"Title":@"A",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]]
                        },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"F",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]
                        },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"E",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[]
                           },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"C",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]
                        },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"D",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]
                        },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"B",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]
                        },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"E",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":@[]
                        },

                       @{
                           @"Title":@"G",
                           @"value":@"1",
                           @"priority":[NSNull null]
                        }
                       ];



  NSArray *sortedArray =  [mainArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *dic1, NSDictionary *dic2) {

        int priority1 = 0,priority2 = 0;

        if([[dic1 objectForKey:@"priority"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[dic1 objectForKey:@"priority"];
            if(arr.count != 0)
                priority1 = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        }

        if([[dic2 objectForKey:@"priority"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
            NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[dic2 objectForKey:@"priority"];
            if(arr.count != 0)
                priority2 = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        }

        if(priority1 > priority2) return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if(priority1 < priority2) return NSOrderedDescending;
        else return NSOrderedSame;

    }];



> The OutPut is in my LOG:
> 
> 2014-11-10 12:09:20.925 Sort Array[1624:591502] sorted array: (
>         {
>         Title = D;
>         priority =         (
>             5
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = A;
>         priority =         (
>             4
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = C;
>         priority =         (
>             3
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = B;
>         priority =         (
>             2
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = F;
>         priority =         (
>             1
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = E;
>         priority =         (
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = E;
>         priority =         (
>         );
>         value = 1;
>     },
>         {
>         Title = G;
>         priority = "<null>";
>         value = 1;
>     } )
```

Comment: If anyBody have any efficient answer than my answer plz let me know I would really appreciate :)